# what is the difference between Items and Elements in an XSD Schema?

Tags: c#, xsd

what is the difference between xmlschema.Items xmlschema.Elements ? They seem to return different things altogether ? what should i use when ? What should i do if i just want to simply get all the elements defined in the XSD sequentially ? I have used the .Items and .Elements approach , both give me different results , i am not sure which one would fit my use .

```
foreach(var entry in xmlschema.Elements)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",entry.Key,entry.Value);
            }
 foreach (var obj in xmlschema.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",obj.GetType());
            }
```

Update :-
and why do both not pick up these

```
<attribute name="ref" type="IDREF"/>
  <attribute name="sequenceID" type="integer"/>
<element name="Metadata" type="s:MetadataType" abstract="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.elements.aspx) collection is a Post Schema Validation Infoset (PSVI) that captures only elements defined at the schema level.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/616fabdz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN talks about PSVI.

The [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.items.aspx) collection is pre-validation; those are [XmlSchemaObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaobject.aspx)s defined at the schema level; they are in XML Schema source order.

As to using pre- vs. post-validation, it is a matter of requirements. For example, if you want to traverse the definitions in "source" order, then you would follow the non-PSVI; if all you want is to get to the infoset, the PSVI is your best bet; or if you have to be able to handle schemas that load but don't compile, then you're stuck with non-PSVI.

If you want elements in source order, you can only do so through the Items collection.

Global (schema level) attributes are showing up under [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.attributes.aspx) collection.

Everything that's global, must show up in the Items collection, except for external references (xsd:include, xsd:import and xsd:redefine) that are showing up under [Includes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.includes.aspx).

If something that's defined at the schema level doesn't show up in the Items collection, that would be a bug. I have to say though that I've never seen it before - please double check that what you're looking for is indeed defined as a child of the xsd:schema element.